# Best practice for adding elements to an ArrayList during object construction?

Tags: java, arraylist

So I'm working on a project for my online AP Computer Science class and have run into a problem... Here's the original class definition I was given to build upon (stripped of code irrelevant to my question):

*Note: The constructor of the Bin class accepts a single argument, a String. The String is representative of the Bin's name.*

```
import java.util.*;
public class Warehouse
{
    // Declare instance variables here

    public Warehouse( int binMax )
    {
        myBinMax = binMax;
        myCatalog = new ArrayList<MusicMedia>();
        myBins = new ArrayList<Bin>( 5 );
        // Code that will start the warehouse
        // off with 5 empty bins
    }

    public void addBin()
    {
        myBins.add( new Bin( "B" + myBins.size() ) );
    }
}
```

My job is to replace the areas commented out with actual code implementation. While the declaration of the instance variables is very straight forward, I'm rather torn on the best way to implement the code mentioned in the second comment.

In short, which is the best way to complete the above constructor?

**Solution A:**

```
private int myBinMax;
private ArrayList<MusicMedia> myCatalog;
private ArrayList<Bin> myBins;

public Warehouse( int binMax )
{
    myBinMax = binMax;
    myCatalog = new ArrayList<MusicMedia>();
    myBins = new ArrayList<Bin>( 5 );
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        myBins.add( new Bin( "B" + myBins.size() ) );
    }
}
```

**Solution B:**

```
private int myBinMax;
private ArrayList<MusicMedia> myCatalog;
private ArrayList<Bin> myBins;

public Warehouse( int binMax )
{
    myBinMax = binMax;
    myCatalog = new ArrayList<MusicMedia>();
    myBins = new ArrayList<Bin>( 5 );
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        addBin(); // <= Is this considered bad practice?
    }
}
```

**Solution C:**

```
// Some magical wizard code I would have never thought of. XD
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think A is clearer, IMO. C would be nice too. Let's call Hermione and ask her some help ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use Java 8?

```
final List<Bin> bins = IntStream.range(0, 5).
        mapToObj(i -> new Bin("Bin" + i)).
        collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Otherwise, both your solutions looks fine. I would prefer `B` as you already have an `addBin` method **with one caveat**. You must make `addBin` `final` as it is a `public` method. You should only call `private` or `final` methods from constructors otherwise you risk someone (possibly you) overriding that method in a subclass and then the subclasses method will be called from the superclass constructor before the subclass is initialized.

Comment: I fail to see how this solutions is better/more elegant/shorter than a simple `for` loop.

Comment: ... Now that code is quality Solution C material, haha. I'm afraid my teacher would be suspicious if I were to implement it into my project, as I would be lying if I claimed to fully understand it. The second part of your answer (private & final methods) hit the nail on the head though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try to use a constant than magic numbers in code :)

```
import java.util.*;
public class Warehouse
{
    // Declare instance variables here
        private static final int INITIAL_BINS = 5;
        private static final String DEFAULT_BINNAME = "DefaultBin_";

    public Warehouse( int binMax )
    {
        myBinMax = binMax;
        myCatalog = new ArrayList<MusicMedia>();
        myBins = new ArrayList<Bin>( INITIAL_BINS );
        for(int i = 0; i < INITIAL_BINS; i++)
        {
            myBins.add( new Bin( DEFAULT_BINNAME + i ) );
            //addBin();// This is fine too depends on how flexible you want naming to be:)
        }
    }

    public void addBin()
    {
        myBins.add( new Bin( "B" + myBins.size() ) );

    }
}
```

Comment: I actually like the implementation of class variables here. If I had the reputation points (because for some reason 15 are required) I would certainly up vote this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with most everything that's already been said, the java 8 functional programming style one-liner is pretty sexy. Magic numbers / strings should be avoided. If your class hasn't gone over functional style why not move the entire for loop into its own function? Generally the only thing that a constructor should do is initialize the state of your object. To make that explicit I try to keep to one line per member variable and that one line is nothing more than an initialization statement. IMO methods (which can reference the current state of the object) shouldn't be called from a constructor because your object hasn't been created yet. If you want to add functions to help you initialize your object, feel free to do so but keep them static so that the intent of the function (not referring to the state of the object) is clear.

```
...
private static final int INITIAL_BIN_COUNT = 5;
private static final String BIN_PREFIX = "B";
private final List<Bin> myBins;

public Warehouse(...) {
    ....
    myBins = initMyBins();
}

private static List<Bin> initMyBins() {
    final List<Bin> result = new ArrayList<Bin>(INITIAL_BIN_COUNT);
    for(int i = 0; i < INITIAL_BIN_COUNT; i++) {
        result.add(new Bin(BIN_PREFIX+i));
    }
    return result;
}
...
```

P.S. A few other notes, it's generally good practice to code to interface types rather than concrete class types (maybe you haven't covered interfaces yet, but that's what I did changing ArrayList to List.